# Accessing metafields on storefront in BigCommerce

Tags: bigcommerce

I'm currently working on a solution where I need to extend Product information with additional (custom) data. I chose to store it in metafields as they may be more complex than a simple custom field (limit to 250 chars) plus they need to be readonly for admin personell. I want to access these fields in the storefront template.

[I see that there's a permission option for metafiels](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/store-management/catalog/product-metafields/createproductmetafield) `read_and_sf_access` (setting storefront access for the metafield) but no info how that can be accessed.

On the other hand the [product theme object](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/theme-objects/product) does not have any attribute for metafields.

How can I access product metafields in a stencil template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the [GraphQL query to fetch the metafields](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/reference-docs/front-matter-reference#graphql-attributes) into the Front Matter at the top of the parent page template, for example product.html

And then from there, you can access it like any other handlebars property (under the `gql` top-level key) - so you may need to pass the result into your component for example.

Here's what that might look like in product.html:

```
---
product:
   videos:
       limit: {{theme_settings.productpage_videos_count}}
   reviews:
       limit: {{theme_settings.productpage_reviews_count}}
   related_products:
       limit: {{theme_settings.productpage_related_products_count}}
   similar_by_views:
       limit: {{theme_settings.productpage_similar_by_views_count}}
gql: "query productMetafieldsById($productId: Int!) {
  site {
    product(entityId: $productId) {
      metafields(namespace: \"my-namespace\") {
        edges {
          node {
            key
            value
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
"
```

You would then access this via `{{gql.data.site.product.metafields}}`

An easy way to consume it would look like:

```
{{#each gql.data.site.product.metafields.edges}}
  {{#with node}}
    {{key}}
    {{value}}
  {{/with}}
{{/each}}
```

Metafields will only be available in the storefront if they have a `permission_set` containing `storefront`, otherwise they will be hidden from the storefront.

You can also invoke the [GraphQL API directly from the Stencil frontend](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-docs/storefront/graphql/graphql-storefront-api-overview#querying-within-a-bigcommerce-storefront) if you prefer, and you can test your queries using the ["Storefront API Playground" under Advanced Settings in the control panel.](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-docs/storefront/graphql/graphql-storefront-api-overview#accessing-the-graphql-playground)